# Vue js template rendering issue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

First time with `vue`. I am learning it playing around with some examples from Laracasts. I cannot get external template to render and the console shows `cannot find element: #toolbar-chat`.

My template is:

```
<template>
    <div id="toolbar-chat">
        <div class="toolbar-chat">
            <ul v-for="chat in messages">
                <li><b>@{{ chat.nickname }} says:</b> @{{ chat.message }}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
            <input class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Type message..." required="required"  maxlength="140" v-model="newMsg">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" @click="press">
                    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {

    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    },

    data() {
        return {
            nickname: [],
            message: ''
        }
    },

    ready() {
        Echo.channel(chat_channel)
            .listen('ChatMessageWasReceived', (data) => {
                // Push data to messages list.
                this.messages.push({
                    message: data.chat.message,
                    nickname: data.player.nickname
                });
            });
    },

    methods: {
        press() {
            // Send message to backend.
            this.$http.post(chat_send_route, {message: this.newMsg})
                .then((response) => {
                    // Clear input field.
                    this.newMsg = '';
                });
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

My HTML contains the following tag:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" id="toolbarChat">
    <my-chat></my-chat>
</div>
```

My `vue` component call is inside a document ready function like this:

```
require('./../app/bootstrap');

$(document).ready(function()
{
    ....
    // Set up chat
    Vue.component('my-chat', require('./../generic/chat.vue'));

    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#toolbar-chat'
    });
});
```

And I include `vue` in my `bootstrap` file like this, then compile with `webpack` and no errors.

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
```

Why is my `HTML template` not rendering?

Comment: Couple things. Where is `new Vue(...)`? Also, `ready()` is a Vue 1 lifecycle event and doesn't exist in Vue 2.

Comment: Chang the id in the HTML to `toolbar-chat` not `<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" id="toolbarChat">`.

Comment: Hi @Bert, thanks! I was missing from my Q the `new vue` and I have added it. I will remove removed `ready` event as you mention. I can now see an error `template not found #toolbar-chat` so it is not pulling in the template still.

Comment: See above comment.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Pls answer the Q and I will upvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML you have the following div:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" id="toolbarChat">
    <my-chat></my-chat>
</div>
```

Change it to

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" id="toolbar-chat">
    <my-chat></my-chat>
</div>
```

Because that is the id that `new Vue({el: "#toolbar-chat",...})` is looking for.